# How to create interactive graphic with Vaadin?

Tags: java, canvas, vaadin

I want to develop a simple interactive game (like arcanoid). I already have implemented a menu and different views, and now I need to develop the actually game (draw flying ball, some movable platform) and I don't know how to do this. I need something like canvas where I can draw my graphic each frame.

I have tryed to implement this with [Canvas](https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/canvas:vaadin) and Timer. But it doesn't want update graphic itself, but only when user clicks on screen or similar. Also I saw com.google.gwt.canvas.client.Canvas, but I cannot understand how to use it in Vaadin application.

So my question is next: is it possible to draw some graphic each frame with high framerate in any way? If possible, how can I do this?

P.S. I use the Vaadin 7.3.3.

Comment: a "high framerate" will be very hard to achieve since its all-HTML we're talking here. Vaadin will encapsulate all of this but because of that you _will_ run into performance problems at some point. Your best advice will be : forget about "games" in pure-HTML (JS) websites unless you're using elements which are guaranteed to be accelerated - the canvas-support in vaadin is BETA hence will not always work as expected. You are using the wrong language, HTML wasnt made for games.

Comment: Ok, but I saw much simple games on HTML and JS. I understand that I can't achieve AAA game with 3D, but I want just a flying 2d ball =). Is it not possible with using Vaadin, maybe with some customization?

Comment: And I haven't any problems with using "unstable" canvas, it is not commercial product, just for learning.

Comment: trying to "learn" anything via the hardest possible approach (games) will most certainly result in a failure. Dont try to take over the world just yet, start with simple websites, proceed with simple JS on these and finally start learning a real programming language like Java or something similar. You can create 2D/3D-games with Java and even make them accessible inside a browser ...

Comment: Thanks for advises. But I still looking for answer of my question. I don't know Vaadin so well (and Java too), but as I know it generates JS+HTML according to Java code (through using GWT). So I looking for a way using client-side Canvas to draw some simple interactive graphic.

Comment: there are lots of addons out there that use e.g. D3. see https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Integrating%20a%20JavaScript%20component https://github.com/kaismh/vaadin-gauge.  same like this you can also use a gaming framework.

Comment: Look into Functional UIs with Vaadin...

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand how the functional programming can help me with my problem... Maybe you can give some example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**ADDED LATER:**

[Here is a link to my educational project with implementation below.](https://github.com/Crabar/Craberoid)
I'll be glad if it helps someone.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**:

Well... I found the solution myself. First of all, I have created my own widget - "client side" component (according to this [article](http://morevaadin.com/content/using-gwt-widgets-part-1/)).

Client side part:

```
public class GWTMyCanvasWidget extends Composite {

public static final String CLASSNAME = "mycomponent";
private static final int FRAMERATE = 30;

public GWTMyCanvasWidget() {
    canvas = Canvas.createIfSupported();
    initWidget(canvas);
    setStyleName(CLASSNAME);
}
```

Connector:

```
@Connect(MyCanvas.class)
public class MyCanvasConnector extends AbstractComponentConnector {    

    @Override
    public Widget getWidget() {
        return (GWTMyCanvasWidget) super.getWidget();
    }

    @Override
    protected Widget createWidget() {
        return GWT.create(GWTMyCanvasWidget.class);
    }
}
```

Server side part:

```
public class MyCanvas extends AbstractComponent {

    @Override
    public MyCanvasState getState() {
        return (MyCanvasState) super.getState();
    }
}
```

Then I just add `MyCanvas` component on my View:

```
private void createCanvas() {
    MyCanvas canvas = new MyCanvas();
    addComponent(canvas);
    canvas.setSizeFull();
}
```

And now I can draw anything on Canvas (on client side in GWTMyCanvasWidget) with great performance =). Example:

```
public class GWTMyCanvasWidget extends Composite {

    public static final String CLASSNAME = "mycomponent";
    private static final int FRAMERATE = 30;
    private Canvas canvas;
    private Platform platform;
    private int textX;

    public GWTMyCanvasWidget() {
        canvas = Canvas.createIfSupported();
        canvas.addMouseMoveHandler(new MouseMoveHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onMouseMove(MouseMoveEvent event) {
                if (platform != null) {
                    platform.setCenterX(event.getX());
                }
            }
        });
        initWidget(canvas);
        Window.addResizeHandler(new ResizeHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onResize(ResizeEvent resizeEvent) {
                resizeCanvas(resizeEvent.getWidth(), resizeEvent.getHeight());
            }
        });
        initGameTimer();
        resizeCanvas(Window.getClientWidth(), Window.getClientHeight());
        setStyleName(CLASSNAME);
        platform = createPlatform();
    }

    private void resizeCanvas(int width, int height) {
        canvas.setWidth(width + "px");
        canvas.setCoordinateSpaceWidth(width);
        canvas.setHeight(height + "px");
        canvas.setCoordinateSpaceHeight(height);
    }

    private void initGameTimer() {
        Timer timer = new Timer() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                drawCanvas();
            }
        };

        timer.scheduleRepeating(1000 / FRAMERATE);
    }

    private void drawCanvas() {
        canvas.getContext2d().clearRect(0, 0, canvas.getCoordinateSpaceWidth(), canvas.getCoordinateSpaceHeight());
        drawPlatform();
    }

    private Platform createPlatform() {
        Platform platform = new Platform();
        platform.setY(Window.getClientHeight());
        return platform;
    }

    private void drawPlatform() {
        canvas.getContext2d().fillRect(platform.getCenterX() - platform.getWidth() / 2, platform.getY() - 100, platform.getWidth(), platform.getHeight());
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you share your project via a service like BitBucket or GitHub. That would be quite  helpful and educational to others.

Comment: Sure, I can share this project. Especially, if someone finds it useful :).